# Declared Shared Preferences in Android causes error when run on Android device?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, shared

The IDE doesn't seem to detect any error. But when the system is run on the physical device, the system crashes when it gets to this class. What seems to be the problem? Could it be the shared preferences declared? How can I fix this?

```
    package com.example.mobile_app;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class Post_4 extends Activity {
    static int time = Post_1.getTime(), post_error = Post_3.get_pos_err();
    int percent;
    float quotient_Float = (float)post_error/(float)time; 
    float computation=0;
    SharedPreferences value = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Values", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = value.edit();
    TextView percentage_display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_4);
        percentage_display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Store();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.post_4, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void Store(){
        computation=value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float)-quotient_Float/value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float);
        if(value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float)==0.0f || quotient_Float < value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float))
        {
            editor.putFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float);
            editor.commit();
            if(value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float)==0.0f)
                percentage_display.setText("System cannot make comparison on first use."); 
            else
                percentage_display.setText("POSITIVE by "+Math.round(computation*100)+"%."); 
        }
        else
            percentage_display.setText("NEGATIVE by "+Math.round(computation*100)+"%."); 
        }
}
```

Error Log:

```
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mobile_app/com.example.mobile_app.Post_4}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1991)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4797)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at com.example.mobile_app.Post_4.<init>(Post_4.java:16)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1982)
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: POST THE CRASH LOG PLEASE

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences value = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Values", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = value.edit();
```

Move this two lines to the function Store. In your case When the class is created it will try to access the context of the application using `getApplicationContext` function by the time the context wont be created so wait for the `onCreate` to happen and then save these two values. Hope this will help.

It is clear from the crash log that the context is not created. See this line

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 01:42:59.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29985):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
```

Do some thing like this instead.

```
SharedPreferences value;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_4);
    percentage_display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    value = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Values",  MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = value.edit();
    Store();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_4);
    percentage_display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SharedPreferences value =getSharedPreferences("Values",  MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = value.edit();
    Store();
}
```

Comment: there is differnce of calling sharedprefrence from activity

Comment: They are both instances of Context, but the application instance is tied to the lifecycle of the application, while the Activity instance is tied to the lifecycle of an Activity. Thus, they have access to different information about the application environment.

Comment: What you are talking have no relation with what I have posted. And also the answer I gave is perfect why you want to post the same answer again.

Comment: Dear i am not posting the same answer i just differentiate the calling mechanism of sharedpreference beacause Christopher Treanor has occured the null pointer at line 16

Comment: No diff in application context and activity context both will return the same sahred pref instance